# Proof of the Ballot Theorem Random Walks

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

> Ballot Theorem: For $b>0$ the number of paths (0,0) to (n,b) that do not revisit the x axis is $\frac{b}{n}\mathbb{P}_{0}(S_n=b)$.

**MY ATTEMPT**
Now the first step of this path is to the point (1,1) so we want to find $$\mathbb{P}_{1}(S_{n-1}=b)- \mathbb{P}^{0}_{1}(S_{n-1}=b)$$ **DEFINE $\mathbb{P}^{0}_{1}$ AS PROBABILITY STARTING AT 1 TO HIT b IN N-1 MOVES  AND HITTING ZERO ON THE WAY**

This by the reflective property is equivalent to $$\mathbb{P}_{1}(S_{n-1}=b)- \mathbb{P}_{-1}(S_{n-1}=b)$$ Now by using the formula $$\mathbb{P}_{a}(S_{n}=b)=\binom{n}{\frac{n+b-a}{2}}p^{\frac{n+b-a}{2}}q^{\frac{n-b+a}{2}}$$ But when I plug the numbers into the functions I am having a hard time rearragning it to give me the desired $\frac{b}{n}\mathbb{P}_{0}(S_n=b)$.
Is this proof reliant on all that algebra or is there a simply way of deriving the result?

Comment: You seem to have confused the notions of "number of paths" and their probabilities. Your statement of the Ballot Thm reflects this. The Reflection Principle also refers to numbers of paths rather than their probabilities (unless applied to symmetric walks) so your use of that is not right.